# How to have solid block emphasising a section

Tags: sectioning, resume

I would like to recreate something similar to the below in Latex. I know how to configure margins, page size, header formatting and spacing etc. but I am not sure how to go about making the solid left hand blocks of different colors which should fit the length of the section.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

A second more minor point is the best way to "tab stop" the date over to the right for each list item.

[image: resume]

Comment: have you seen [How to choose which sides of the border to draw in a `framebox`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40314)? seems like it might be relevant!

Comment: Thanks - mdframed looks like exactly what I need. If you put this as an answer I would accept it.

Comment: Hi thrope- that's great, I'm glad it helps :) I think I would rather vote to close as a duplicate if that's ok with you :)