# Line down the side of the page

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

At the moment I'm using the {tabular} environment to distinguish examples in a document I'm writing:

```
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
\emph{Example} & [Lots of text and equations]
\end{tabular}
```

It makes it so that there's a nice line running down the left side of my page over the course of the example. The only problem is that it doesn't behave well with page breaks. I know the package longtable works for continuing tables onto several pages but since I have everything in one table entry, it doesn't work for me.

I realise I'm completely misusing {tabular} and am looking for an environment that will give me the same effect, but will continue the effect onto successive pages.

Comment: `mdframed` is the only way to go for this kind of thing- I think you'll find what you're looking for in, for example, [How to choose which sides of the border to draw in a `framebox`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40314)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two simple examples showing two possibilities: one with [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) and the other one with [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox); the advantage of these packages over `framed` is that they offer endless customization possibilities with a simple `key=value` interface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,paperwidth=18cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newmdtheoremenv[
hidealllines=true,
leftline=true,
innertopmargin=0pt,
innerbottommargin=0pt,
linewidth=4pt,
linecolor=gray!40,
innerrightmargin=0pt,
innertopmargin=-6pt,
]{examplei}{Example}

\newtcolorbox{exampleii}{
freelance,
breakable,
width=\dimexpr\textwidth+28pt\relax,
before=\par\vspace{\bigskipamount}\noindent,
enlarge left by=-14pt,
overlay unbroken and first={
  \node[
  anchor=north east,
  inner xsep=8pt,
  xshift=8pt,
  rounded corners=5pt,
  font=\bfseries,
  fill=white] at ([xshift=-0.2cm]frame.north west) (tit) {\strut Example:};
  \draw[
  line width=3pt,
  rounded corners=5pt,gray
  ] ([xshift=4pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=4pt]frame.south west);
},
overlay middle and last={
  \draw[
  line width=3pt,
  rounded corners=5pt,gray
  ] ([xshift=4pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=4pt]frame.south west);
},
frame code={},
interior code={},
top=0pt,
bottom=0pt
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{examplei}
\lipsum[4]
\end{examplei}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{examplei}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{examplei}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{exampleii}
\lipsum[4]
\end{exampleii}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{exampleii}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{exampleii}
\lipsum[4-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The page layout was changed just for the example.

You can also take a look at the answer to [Typesetting a definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124847/3954) for more examples and variations (the code in that answer can be easily adapted to produce the label "Example" instead of "Definition").

Comment: when I compile your example the last mdframe becomes funny, I believe it happens because it breaks the page. I do not know how to solve this problem. Any idea?

Comment: @saldenisov When I compile my example, the result is the one in the image and I don't see anything funny. Perhaps you are using some different settings? In any case, we would need to see the offending code. please consider opening a new question.

Comment: I've added `colback=white,colframe=white` and now it does what it should.

Answer (score 2):

MWE using the package `framed`, edited to have enough text to break the page:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{framed}
\newenvironment{example}%
{\begin{leftbar}\begin{quotation}}%
{\end{quotation}\end{leftbar}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{example}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Want to change how thick your line is and how far from your text it's set? Add this to the preamble after you `\usepackage{framed}`:

```
\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{\vrule width 1pt \hspace{5pt}}%
  \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}
```

where `\vrule width Xpt` (in this case, changed to 1pt) sets the thickness of your vertical rule and `\hspace{Ypt}`, set to 5pt here, is the space from your line to your text.

You can also use the native `leftbar` environment if you don't want to deal with the other formating that comes with the `quotation` environment. Just frame your example text with

```
\begin{leftbar}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{leftbar}
```

and the same customization options in the preamble will apply.