# \ulcorner without padding to letter

Tags: spacing

I'm trying to achieve this with `\ulcorner`:

[image: Goal]

But I'm just getting

[image: wrong]

with `^\ulcorner R`.

Any ideas how I can get rid of the padding between the corner and the letter?

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to choose which sides of the border to draw in a `framebox`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40314/5764)

Comment: @Werner Do you think the first one is made with `framebox`?

Comment: you could add negative space such as `\!`

Comment: Probably not, since the rules have rounded edges. `\framebox` draws rules with flat ends.

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution to write (say) `\ulc{R}` and have a `\ulcorner` as a prefix to `R`, but then have it extendable to (say) `\urc{R}` and have `\urcorner` as a suffix to `R`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution depends on the used fonts, sizes, math style, ...
Adjust the parameters accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand*{\ulcR}{\raisebox{1.5pt}{\rlap{$\ulcorner$}\kern.5pt}R}
\begin{document}
\[ \ulcR \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]